# Selecting App from UIDocumentInteractionController throws "LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, instagram

For some very odd reason when I try and select an app displayed in a UIDocumentInteractionController nothing happens. The console is logging a `LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called` error and I've looked around to try and find a fix, but I'm coming up with nothing.

Below is my code to send a photo in app to Instagram. The menu pops up just fine and displays Instagram as the only option as I want it to, but when I click it nothing happens other than the console message mentioned earlier.

```
- (void)addToInstagram
{
    // Save image to temporary file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"add_to_insta.igo"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.energy.image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
    NSString *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/add_to_insta.igo"];
    NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];

    // Pass into Instagram app
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 612);
    self.docFile = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
    self.docFile.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    self.docFile.annotation = @{@"InstagramCaption": @"#capturedby_____"};

    [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"]]){
        [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
    }else{
        UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Instagram" message:@"You do not have Instagram installed." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorView show];
    }
}
```

Has anyone else encountered this error by chance?

Comment: I got the same error on iOS 8. Unfortunately not got any solution.

Comment: I actually figured it out late last night. Basically what was happening was the image file was coming in as a `nil` value so nothing was launching. Once I solved the image saving issue everything worked as intended (although the error still appears in the console).

Comment: I checked the image also which is not null and I am sharing file through mail, the mail app shows the image is attached but getting the warning and printing large logs in console. The logs looks like printing NSData.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the UIDocumentInteractionController delegate? I receive the same message but setting the delegate allows to present the document picker.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to the main thread:

```
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {

        [self.docFile presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];

      });
```

Comment: didn't work. i'm having same problem here, but this way didn't worked